# What are the steps for finding points on finite field elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves

New to the crypto world and I can't figure this basic thing out, embarrassingly.

Bitcoin uses secp256k1's elliptic curve y^2 = x^3 + 7 mod(p)

Let's pretend p is 9. Using this little website:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/andreacorbellini/ecc/920b29a/interactive/modk-add.html

You can plug in the parameters, e.g.: a = 1, b = 7, p = 9.

I don't understand how the points are being calculated. 
they say x=3,y=4 and x=3,y=5 are points. 
How?

(3^3+7) mod(9) = 34 mod(9) = 7

Sqrt(7) != 4 nor 5.

Can someone walk me through the steps - obviously I'm missing something simple. Thanks!

Comment: You have to use [modular square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) here.

Comment: $p=9$ doesn't work; to use the above formula, $p$ has to be prime.  Now, you can define an elliptic curve over $GF(9)$ (as 9 is a prime power), but the formula looks different (and doesn't involve a modulo 9 operation)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373125/solve-for-x-in-elliptic-curve-y2-x3-ax-b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your question:

$y^2 = x^3 + 7 \mod 9$

For $x=3$ you get $y^2 = 34 \equiv 7 \mod 9$. The two solutions are $y=4$ and $y=5$. Check this by inserting those values into the equation, i.e. $4^2 = 16 \equiv 7 \mod 9$ or $5^2 = 25 \equiv 7 \mod 9$.

This is basic number theory, where an integer $q$ is called a quadratic residue modulo $n$ if it is congruent to a perfect square modulo $n$, i.e. there exists the integer $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv q \mod n$.

I would recommend you to read into basic modular arithmetic first, then move on to elliptic curves and then having grasped those two topics, moving to applications that make use of them (such as Bitcoin). Here's [a link](http://spark-university.s3.amazonaws.com/stanford-crypto/slides/10.3-numth-annotated.pdf) to a university level introduction to number theory by professor Dan Boneh, who by the way uploaded most of his cryptography classes on YouTube.

Comment: y^2=7mod9 ? or y^2=34mod9

Comment: $y^2 = 34 \equiv 7 \mod 9$, as $34 \mod 9$ is congruent to $7 \mod 9$.